# Generating the URL of a nested resource without its parent (without using shallow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

In our application, many resources are nested under a common resource representing an organization. Most URLs include an organization ID the following pattern: `/:organization_id/notifications/:id`.

My problem is that I always have to give the current organization to generate the URL to any model. For example, the link to an existing notification would be `link_to [@organization, @notification]`.

Since a notification already belongs to an organization, I was wondering if it was possible to generate my URL using `link_to @notification` and it would actually generate a URL including the organization ID of the notification. I was hoping that a configuration in the model would be able to achieve this but I could not find anything in the guides, the docs or the source code of Rails.

I would like to keep the organization ID visible in the URL as this is an information that is used by our customers. So I do not want to use shallow nested resources for this problem.

We are using Rails 5.2.0.

Comment: Sorry I posted a wrong answer as you want to keep organization id in the URL. Just get the organization from the notification variable like `link_to some_notification_path(@notification.organization.id, @notification.id)` Then you write the helper with the `@notification` variable only. (this work only if Notification is a direct child of Organization, if not, you have to grab the whole tree, or make a  `through:` child)

Comment: Helpers are a solution, an ugly one but a solution. This would require a lot of boilerplate code to work with forms for example. The route solution is better and allows me to fine-tune the URL for any model depending on its data. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`resolve` route definition method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-resolve).

It is designed to do exactly what you want: configure a different behaviour when a single model instance is passed to `url_for` (as `link_to` does, for example).

Specifically, in your `config/routes.rb`, something like:

```
resolve("Notification") do |note|
  [:notification_organization, note.organization, note]
end
```

It sounds like you were on the right track -- it's just a routing concern rather than a model one.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what functionality ended up shipping, so I'll leave this out of the answer for now, but it may also work as just `[note.organization, note]` -- without the explicit route name symbol.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad that it does not work with complex URL for now, but this will solve a lot of my problems. Thanks.